# Using StringFormat to format set of digits (not currency or number) from a string with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I am working with WPF and C# and I want to format a set of digits (not currency or number) with `StringFormat` in a `TextBlock`.

Example: `456321789` (string)

And I want to show it in the `TextBlock` like `456 321 789`.

This examples doesn't work:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=000 000 000"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat=### ### ###"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat={}{0:000 000 000}"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Number, StringFormat={}{0:### ### ###}"/>
```

Sometime ago I tried to format a set of 7 digits like `5432-123`. And I wasn't successful.

I tried many examples, and noting works with. What I am doing wrong?

Note: The only way I can achieve this is if I have the set of digits as an integer. But I'd like to understand why I can't do it with a string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, actually you can do it with string if you parse it back to number first :) Just noone needed such a format for a generic string, that's why it's not implemented out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string formats you are using are only applicable to integers, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). So in order to get the desired formatting, you have to bind to a number. not a string.

If you think a little, there is a reason behind that: the formatting like digit grouping is only interesting for numbers and not to generic strings like "helloworld". So noone cared about implementing such formats for generic string.

Sorry for that.

(A question aside: if your data is guaranteed to be a string representation of a number, why don't you keep the value as an `int` then?)

Comment: The reason is because i am importing data from Excel files regularly to the Database. So the situation is one of the columns stores references. The references are a set 9 digits. But the "problem" is because some of this references contains preceding zeros. So when i get the value from the Cell and i convert it to integer, the preceding zeros are skipped. And because i validate all the imported data, i will check if the number has 9 digits, which in some cases will not have. Its the reason why i was trying to work with a string. But the truth is only the preceding zeros will be skipped...

Comment: And with one of the StringFormats above i can show the 9 digits to the user.

Comment: @Miguel: well, you should store not the representation but the real object, in this case it's int. If you need to store the formatting information, you ought to store it beside the int value. This way everything is going to work without problems.

Comment: @Miguel: well, the format specifier with min output width is valid not only for numbers, that's why. But the others are valid only for numbers.